# Android barcode button - I can't handle event

Tags: javascript, cordova, events, barcode

I bought this [Android phone + barcode scanner](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Unique-Design-High-Capacity-4000mA-Android-Barcode-Scanner/32378561712.html?spm=2114.40010608.4.1.BELCM9). I am using Phonegap (Cordova) and I want to build an app for Android in HTML + Javascript. Unfortunately I can't detect the "scan" button press (in the center of the phone).

It works if I focus input and I will press the "scan" button. The scanner puts the barcode into the input, but like I wrote, I can't handle this event (keydown, keyup, click, past .... not working).

I need to detect this event because I want to focus to the input if the barcode scan button is pressed.

Comment: How should we help without code???

Comment: I tried lot of codes, no one works. I am asking you if you know way how handle this event? I don't have code ..